# "Missing MSCVP140.dll" and "Missing VCRUNTIME140.dll" when running an .exe-File on another computer

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I made a program in Microsoft Visual Studio C++ and used the SFML for this. I included the correct .dll-Files, that the program needed, and copied them into the "Release"-Folder. It worked. The entire program worked flawless on my computer, but as soon as I tried to run it on another computer, it said: `Missing "MSVCP140.dll"` and `Missing "VCRUNTIME140.dll`.

I searched for a solution of this program, and always heared "Go to Project > Project Settings > C/C++ > Code generation > Runtime libraries > switch to Multi-Threaded (/MT). I compiled the project with this settings, and the executable increased in size, which they said is normal, because there are no supporting .dll-Files anymore.

But as I tried it again, with the new .exe, it gave me the exact same Error-Messages. Are there any other possibilities to solve this WITHOUT installing some -dll-Files onto the computer?

Comment: All you need to do on the other machine is to install the appropriate vcredist for your version of visual studio (one executable to download and run).

Comment: @crashmstr Thanks, I'll try that. But is there a way I can run the exe without installing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is covered on MSDN in some detail. See [Deployment in Visual C++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293574.aspx)

You really have three choices:

- Use the "centralized" versions of the DLLs. For this you should have a setup program that runs the `VCREDIST_*.EXE` packages for VS 2015 or if using a MSI-based setup you can use the MSM files provided.
- Copy the required DLLs as part of your program. This means your installer or zip file or whatever that has the EXE includes the DLLs it needs too. This is the best choice if you want "copy and run" style deployment, but remember that all security servicing of the DLL is now your problem.
- Use static linking. From a security perspective this is the least desired solution, and really should only be used in the specific cases of writing an installer--i.e. the program that installs an app has to run in the first place.

You have not specified which version of Windows is running on your target machine. VS 2015 does *not* support Windows 7 RTM as it's out of support, but it does support Windows 7 Service Pack 1 along with Windows Vista Service Pack 2, Windows 8.x, and Windows 10.

> While we are on the subject note that Windows 8.0 is also out of support. Those users need to upgrade to Windows 8.1 Update or Windows 10.

Comment: Man, thank you very much, the two errors are gone now, but now the next problem ocurs: "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc00007b)".

I tried running it on windows 10 and don't know if that's the only OS where this error occurs. I doubt that. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: You should set up a debugging session to find out what's happening.

Comment: This didn't get me anywhere. Any other ideas?

Comment: Is your program built for Debug or Release?

Comment: Release. I'm using sfml also.